# Какие вы знаете библиотеки, чтобы оформить пример кода на сайте?

Tags: html

Нужно оформить примеры кода на сайте. Есть теги `<pre>`, `<code>`, `<xmp>` и прочие. Но хотелось бы, чтобы по нажатию одной кнопки его можно было бы скопировать, была видна нумерация строк и прочее. Можете посоветовать хорошие библиотеки для этого? В интернете довольно скудная информация по этому вопросу или я не правильно спрашиваю у гугла, что я хочу :)

Comment: Такое http://markup.su/highlighter/ , https://tohtml.com/ , http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ , http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать GitHub gists + github gists embed.
Примеры: http://blairvanderhoof.com/gist-embed/
Библиотека: http://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed